# SQL statement error in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access form which contains an insert statement.

The code works very good, but the problem when I enter a text that contains a single quote `'`:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO student (stname) VALUES ('" & stname.Value & "')"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

when `stname.value = Ra'ed or ka'l`

then statement becomes wrong

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Try replacing ' with ''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel, VBA: Parametrized query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117357/excel-vba-parametrized-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I would have to agree with marc_s regarding the SQL injection warning. However for a quick and dirty solution on a non-mission critical db that you don't mind other users potentially hacking into or otherwise messing with, you would use

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO student (stname) VALUES ('" & Replace (stname.Value, "'", "''") & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [DAO parameterized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293459(v=vs.60).aspx#_core_parameterizing_dao_queries) which allows binding values without quote enclosure. Access queries allows the `PARAMETERS` clause which can be binded with external values:

```vb
Dim db As Database
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

' PREPARE STATEMENT (STRING CAN BE A SAVED QUERY)
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [strValParam] Text(255);" _
            & " INSERT INTO student (stname) VALUES ([strValParam]);"

' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF OBJECT (REPLACE EMPTY STRING "" FOR SAVED QUERY NAME AND NO STRSQL)
Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

' BIND VALUE (SINGLE/DOUBLE/SPECIAL CHARS ALL ALLOWED)
qdef!strValParam =  stname.Value

' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
qdef.Execute 

Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```